# "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" while there is no data in referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have two related tables:

```
[GameDataGroup] with PK

[Arena_GameData] with FK
```

I try to execute query:

```
 DELETE FROM [ACP_MAIN_STABLE_DB_content].[dbo].[GameDataGroup] 
 WHERE [key] LIKE '%' + '_test_group' + '%'
```

And have a message:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK__Arena_GameData__GameDataGroup". The conflict occurred in database
>   "ACP_MAIN_STABLE_DB_content", table "dbo.Arena_GameData", column
>   'gameDataGroupId'.

While there is no related data in `"dbo.Arena_GameData", column 'gameDataGroupId'`. Why it is prventing me to delete that record?

The 'FK__Arena_GameData__GameDataGroup' definition:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have trigger on ACP_MAIN_STABLE_DB_content?

Comment: Thanks, how to check if i have trigger? Sorry i'am very new at sql

Comment: It seems i found place, 'Database Triggers", and there i can't see any triggers

Comment: Could you include `FK__Arena_GameData__GameDataGroup` defintion?

Comment: added FK definition screenshots

Comment: Are you sure there is no related data?

Comment: Possible expression LIKE '%' + '_test_group' + '%' was the issue, i replace it with = '_test_group' and problem is gone

Comment: You can put this solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting more results than you expected with your `DELETE` query because `_` is a wildcard character as far as [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is concerned.

So `LIKE '%_test_group%'` will match any text which has at least one character, then the characters `test`, then any character, and then the characters `group`, Optionally followed by any number of characters - unlike what you probably expected of it needing to find exactly the sequence `_test_group`.

You can use escaping if you need to do these sorts of matches - `LIKE '%!_test!_group%' ESCAPE '!'` should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error message while deleting records from the table if any of the records have been `referenced` by any other tables, so you can not delete those records from the table which are having `referenced` by other or you should use `cascade` option to remove those reference as well.