# How can a delete statement conflict with a REFERENCE constraint when there are no matching records in the referenced table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I run a stored procedure that deletes records, then re-populates them from a source system. The delete portion of the SP is structured according to the hierarchical layout of the tables, deleting from a referencing table (lets call it `CHILD_TABLE`) before deleting from referenced table (`PARENT_TABLE`). I am getting the "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint..." error when deleting from `PARENT_TABLE`.

There is a where clause on the delete statement and when I run a select statement with the same where clause I get 11 records returned. So we're trying to delete 11 records.

`CHILD_TABLE` references `PARENT_TABLE` with an FK column containing the `PARENT_TABLE.PRIMARY_KEY`. But when I run a select statement against `CHILD_TABLE`, using either of the following, I get 0 rows returned:

1. Copy and paste `PARENT_TABLE.PRIMARY_KEY` values from above select statement into where clause using `IN`
2. Copy and paste select statement above and put into where clause using `IN` against the FK/PK
3. Copy and paste select statement above and put into where clause using `EXISTS WHERE` etc.

So it looks to me like SQL Server thinks there is data in the `CHILD_TABLE` when there really isn't.

This question looks like a duplicate of ["The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" while there is no data in referenced table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890885/the-delete-statement-conflicted-with-the-reference-constraint-while-there-is-n) but the answer there was (paraphrased) "There actually is data in the referenced table". However, in my case, there really is no data in the referenced table. No, really.

I was wondering if there is an index that is out of date that shows the reference constraint there is data when there really isn't?

Any help/pointers appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to tell when so much abstraction is here rather than real table names and error messages. I know I have, once or twice in the past, skimmed over the text of an error message and assumed I knew which table it was referring to when in fact the error message was referring to a completely different table. Could that be the case here?

Comment: It is unlikely that there is a bug in SQL Server in this area. Most likely you do have data in the referenced table. Maybe there is another pending non-committed transaction that still somehow holds the rows?

Comment: I have triple checked the error message and I and a colleague are 100% certain we are checking the correct table and that there are no matching records in the child table. On a hunch, my colleague used the same logic but inserted PARENT_TABLE.PRIMARY_KEY into a temp table, then deleted from PARENT_TABLE where PARENT_TABLE.PRIMARY_KEY is in the temp table and it deleted the same 11 records. This makes me think there is some issue with an index, where this is using the clustered index but the delete statement including the logic is using a different index.

Comment: Having said the above, I didn't think it was possible to have an index with out of date data?

Comment: Barring data corruption or an engine bug, an "out of date" index isn't possible, as it violates consistency. It is possible for one query to see data another doesn't, but only where uncommitted or locked data is involved. Script the constraint mentioned in the error message to ensure it is actually correct; don't rely on the name. Check for active transactions using `DBCC OPENTRAN`. Check your DB for corruption with `DBCC CHECKDB`. If all that yields nothing, file a bug on Connect.

Comment: In my case, it was two similarly names tables that I was missing. Tks guys.

Comment: Any chance a trigger is inserting, deleting, or updating rows in a way that could lead to the error?

Comment: Or possibly a cascade delete?

Comment: It is a know bug fixed in SQL Server 2019 CU5 https://sqlserverperformace.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found that the underlying issue was linked to the indexing on the table. When I dropped an index that referenced that same column that showed the FK constraint erroneously; the delete statement would work.

Therefore my proposed workaround would be:

- If you need the column to be indexed and have the FK constraint on it to the parent table, alter the existing FK constraint to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
- If you do not need the index, then you may consider dropping it and the issue will be 'resolved'.

I have not been able to create a consistent replication scenario for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this question upvoted so many times,when question is not explain with existing schema definition nor delete script.

`Trigger`,`Cascade delete` is already discuss above.
Or `in-consistence transaction` or `lock` is also discuss above.

I have created a situation where as a new developer i am not aware of full database.

```
CREATE table parent(col int not null primary key)

CREATE table child(col int not null primary key)
CREATE table child1(col2 int not null primary key,col int not null foreign key references parent(col))

--insert into parent VALUES(1),(2),(3)
--insert into child VALUES(1),(2),(3)
--insert into child1 VALUES(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
--select * from parent

begin try
begin transaction
delete from child where col=2

--select * from child where col=2
delete from parent where col=2

COMMIT
end TRY
begin CATCH
if(@@trancount>0)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
THROW;
END CATCH

--select * from child
drop table child1
drop table child
drop table parent
```

Here I am aware of another child table `child1`.so when i try to delete parent like above I get similar error.

So I will run this script,

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) AS ConstraintName, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS ReferencingObject,
OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedObject, *
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns
where OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)='parent'
```

This will reveal me second child table `child1`